# Very slow Riak writes and this error: {shutdown,max_concurrency}

Tags: riak

On a 5-node Riak cluster, we have observed very slow writes - about 2 docs per second. Upon investigation, I noticed that some of the nodes were low on disk space. After making more space available and restarting the nodes, we are see this error (or something similar) on all of the nodes inside `console.log`:

```
 2015-02-20 16:16:29.694 [info] <0.161.0>@riak_core_handoff_manager:handle_info:282 An outbound handoff of partition riak_kv_vnode 182687704666362864775460604089535377456991567872 was terminated for reason: {shutdown,max_concurrency}
```

Currently, the cluster is not being written to or read from.

I would appreciate any help in getting the cluster back to good health.

I will add that we are writing documents to an index that is tied to a Solr index.

This is not critical production data, and I could technically wipe everything and start fresh, but I would like to properly diagnose and fix the issue so that I am prepared to handle it if it should happen in a production environment in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: `{shutdown, max_concurrency}` is sort of a non-error.  It means that the node has some data that needs to be handed off to another node (probably hinted handoff), but that other node is currently processing the limit of transfers.  You can check/set the limit with `riak-admin transfer-limit`.  The transfer that was shutdown due to max_concurrency should be tried again in a few minutes, eventually it will get through.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what it was, but I nuked the cluster and started fresh and it's fine now.